# Link with the image on the left of the text

Tags: html, css, image

Prompt how to make a link with the image of the image to be the background and the left and the text on the right and leveled height. As in [this](http://piccy.info/view3/5643306/59021de72d85aba8112b24698fba081e/) image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: People here are not just going to code for you, put some effort in and show us what you have tried. We are not servants, we are here to help. Also, can you rephrase your question as it is not clear what  you are asking for, and your example is not any help at all.

Answer (score 0):

For the background image:

```
background-image: url("../../image/my_image.gif");
background-position: left center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.Try it! It may your answer.

```
<a href="#">
   <img src="#" alt="image description">
</a>
```